# Why are emails to Microsoft (e.g. Hotmail and Outlook) never being received?

Tags: email, mx-record

I have a form on a WordPress website that, when submitted, sends an email to 4 email addresses. The two gmail.com addresses receive the email. The hotmail.com address and a domain hosted with MS Office fail to be received.

Below are the logs provided by my hosting provider, to show that their server is sending out 4 emails.

But the emails to MS return with extra information, including an email address for a domain name that was only used while I was developing the website. This domain no longer exists.

Why has MS cached this domain name and returning it? (...@charity.myolddomain.co.uk)

---

**Logs**

Oct  1 16:00:05 smtp1 postfix/smtp[25073]: 13B1B3A3DF0: **to=joe.bloggs@gmail.com**, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.166.27]:25, delay=1.1, delays=0.36/0.01/0.18/0.59, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1696176005 t20-20020a0560001a5400b003261a17d4bdsi2488375wry.544 - gsmtp)

Oct  1 16:00:05 smtp1 postfix/smtp[25073]: 13B1B3A3DF0: **to=fredsmith67@gmail.com**, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.166.27]:25, delay=1.1, delays=0.36/0.01/0.18/0.59, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1696176005 t20-20020a0560001a5400b003261a17d4bdsi2488375wry.544 - gsmtp)

Oct  1 16:00:05 smtp1 postfix/smtp[25087]: 13B1B3A3DF0: **to=info@charitygarden.org**, relay=charitygarden-org.mail.protection.outlook.com[52.101.73.6]:25, delay=1.8, delays=0.36/0.01/0.61/0.87, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <**DGN4HEfcV8lOQLrh6eWmjPv7bVMvF1jcS9kRo3HmDE@charity.myolddomain.co.uk**> [InternalId=979252543523, Hostname=DU2PR01MB8735.eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com] 9592 bytes in 0.149, 62.751 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)

Oct  1 16:00:06 smtp1 postfix/smtp[24265]: 13B1B3A3DF0: **to=joe_bloggs@hotmail.com**, relay=hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.55.161]:25, delay=2.7, delays=0.36/0.01/0.86/1.4, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <**DGN4HEfcV8lOQLrh6eWmjPv7bVMvF1jcS9kRo3HmDE@charity.myolddomain.co.uk**> [InternalId=12833362280485, Hostname=PA4P191MB1503.EURP191.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] 8868 bytes in 0.187, 46.194 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery -> 250 2.1.5)

Comment: Show the relevant headers of the mails sent to gmail and you will likely see, it is not Microsoft that is *showing you cached data*, it is you that is *sending old data* to all providers. The only difference being that Microsoft is mentioning your message ID when giving you the empty promise to deliver your message.

Comment: Your hosting provider logs clearly show that THEY are sending to these email addresses. Microsoft hasn't "chached" those email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Search through your servers configuration** and clear up mentions of invalid (unregistered) or inappropriate (not registered by you, authorizing your server) domains.

Microsoft is merely echoing what you sent, and if your messages do still use that old domain in the message ID, your server is still using that domain, possibly in more than one place. Confirm both hostname and envelope sender configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I went through what options I had available, and found that charity.myolddomain.co.uk was still listed in my domains. I have cleaned these up and now the email logs no longer show the old domain. (Although emails are still not going through, but one step at a time ...)

Comment: @vegemite4me You probably still want to [review the headers](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/messageheader/) ("view source") of a successfully received mail (e.g. as found in a google inbox) originating from your website, there might be clues there.

Comment: Just to follow up that the cleaning up of invalid domains fixed the issue. In the headers it looks like SPF could be improved, but works for now. Many thanks anx.